# How can I animate from textfield to list row In SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

For example, how iMessage animates when a message is sent, transitioning from the textField to the tableview/collectionview cell above it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfAPip-QtTc

you can see on 2.57 here

Answer (score 0):

Using offset and opacity you can simulate the transition. I've written a very simple example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var textIn: String = ""
    @State var send: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack{
            ZStack{

                TextField("enter text", text: $textIn)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)

                Text("\(textIn)")
                    .padding(2)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .offset(y: send == true ? -100 : 0)
                    .opacity( send == true ? 1.0 : 0.0)
                    .animation(Animation.easeInOut)
            }

            Button( action: { withAnimation { self.send.toggle() } } ) {
                Text("send Text")

            }.padding(.top, 50)

        }.background(Color.black)

    }
}
```